# Using powershell to set file system ACE

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to set file ACE's using powershell. I have not been able to set the multiple permissions though with the same call to `set-acl`.

So have resorted to making a function and calling the function for each of the permission grants I want to make. Still, `set-acl` is failing to set both Modify and Write permission. I am confused now.

I run the script and only get the write permission set. The Function runs without errors, but I don't get the proper ACE set.

I can't really see why the second call to addaccessrule is clobbering the first call?

```
$StartingDir1 = "C:\_WPCYB"
$StartingDir2 = "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe InDesign CC 2017\Plug-Ins"
$WcolRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Write" 
$McolRights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"Modify"
$InheritanceFlag = System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None 
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 
$objType = [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("HA\Domain Users") 

function set-perm-on-dir ($dir, $perm) {
    # handle the starting directory itself, d1
    echo setting perms on directory $dir setting $perm
    $objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($objUser, WcolRights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 
    echo "New ACE is " $objACE
    $d1 = Get-Item $StartingDir1
    $acla = get-acl $d1
    $acla.AddAccessRule($objACE)
    set-acl -Path $d1.FullName -AclObject $acla
}

set-perm-on-dir -dir $StartingDir1 -perm $WcolRights 
set-perm-on-dir -dir $StartingDir1 -perm $McolRights
```

Comment: Try creating a `[System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity]` object and modifying its permissions from scratch to pass the `Set-Acl -AclObject` argument.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code and it doesn't run without a TON of errors. It looks like you've mashed two scripts together without any idea what you're doing. Have you even tried debugging it at all?

Comment: Strongly consider delegating file-based security work like this to `icacls`. There's no shame in using existing command-line tools, especially if they're much easier to use and leave less room for errors (which is something you want to avoid for ACLs especially).

Comment: James C -- thank you for your helpful comment. Yes, I did run the code and it ran without any errors. I can only guess that perhaps something got lost in copy paste. Though the script ran without error, it still fails to set he write and modify permission on the ACE. The echo statements were attempt to see the state of objects as the script proceeds, and I do see output.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS Permissions are a nightmare to set using native commands, personally I use the [File System Security Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/NTFSSecurity) to do this as it's much easier to understand (its commands are like the actions you perform with the GUI).

To disable Inheritance and grant `Modify` permissions for `Domain\User` it's just two simple commands:

```
$folder = "C:\folder"

Get-Item $folder | Disable-NTFSAccessInheritance
Get-Item $folder | Add-NTFSAccess -Account "Domain\User" -AccessRights Modify
```

---

**EDIT:**

Most modules aren't included with PowerShell, you have to download and install them.

A large amount of them are available from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com) and can be installed using `Install-Module -Name ModuleName` (this command is native with PS v5+ but needs [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/gallery/psgallery/psgallery_gettingstarted) if you're using an older version)

So for the module I use above it's: `Install-Module -Name NTFSSecurity`

Comment: Thank you James C, but I cannot find an Add-NTFSAccess cmdlet. My powershell doesn't include it in lookups and it fails when i try to run. Is it included in some other tool that needs to be installed?

Comment: The *File System Security Module* is linked to in my answer :)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Seems MS has changed the structure for ps module links, I've updated it to point to powershell gallery instead.

Comment: Thanks, @henrycarteruk (I'll remove this comment .. anyone else feel free to flag for removal).